# Toggle idle animation in animator

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have a 2d platformer where the players sprite will change depending on if its idle, jumping, going left or going right. So I have done this just fine using the animator, but I want to introduce a snowy environment that will change the appearance of the player.

So the player has a public bool of snowy which will set the snowy variable in the animator when the player initalises.

This is what my animator looks like:

[image]

It works ok, but even if the players snowy variable is true by default, it will go to the normal idle and then switch to the snowy idle which is very noticible.

Another problem is that it seems to be lagging. This is the reason why I can see the switch as it pauses for about half a second before switching. I notice this when jumping and moving left and right too even though I set the animations to 60fps.

If I could change the idle animation depending on a bool then I could deal with the other lag when switching states, but ideally, id like to fix both.

Comment: That should be the normal behaviour. It starts with idle as default state, then goes to other states. If you don't want to change your current animator what i can suggest is; try to disable exit time on the animation state on idle. With that it should leave the idle state immediately

Comment: Or you can delete the animation in your current idle state, make it empty state, then arrange the rest of the animator.

Comment: Hi, how would i change the exit time on the animation? I have clicked it but i dont see an option

Comment: [link](https://cdngamedevacademy.azureedge.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/HasExitTime.png?x87724) something like this. If this is not changing anything, you could re-arrange your animator as i said in my 2nd comment.

Comment: I will try this, thanks